# jQuery how to use a parent's data-attribute to modify contents of child

Tags: jquery, each, custom-data-attribute

I have this HTML

```
<div data-studentname="Joan Andrews" data-studentdegree="Math II" data-studentgpa="999">
    <div id="name"></div>
    <div id="degree"></div>
    <div id="gpa"></div>
</div>
<div data-studentname="Alex Simmons" data-studentdegree="Science VI" data-studentgpa="0">
    <div id="name"></div>
    <div id="degree"></div>
    <div id="gpa"></div>
</div>
```

What I wanted to do was to let the data attributes set the `.text()` values of the respective children, so it should look like this afterwards

```
<div class="student" data-studentname="Joan Andrews" data-studentdegree="Math II" data-studentgpa="999">
    <div id="name">Joan Andrews</div>
    <div id="degree">Math II</div>
    <div id="gpa">99</div>
</div>
<div class="student" data-studentname="Alex Simmons" data-studentdegree="Science VI" data-studentgpa="0">
    <div id="name">Alex Simmons</div>
    <div id="degree">Science VI</div>
    <div id="gpa">0</div>
</div>
```

I've setup a jQuery file having this

```
$('.student').each(function() {
  var student = $('.student');
  var studentname = student.data('studentname');
  var studentdegree = ability.data('studentdegree');
  var studentgpa = ability.data('studengpa')

  $('#name').text(studentname);
  $('#degree').text(studentdegree);
  $('#gpa').text(studentgpa);
});
```

This only edits the first set of divs under the first `.student` `div` and I don't know what to do now and I'm stuck in this.

I'm half-sure I'm using .each() wrong but this is because I'm unfamiliar with jQUery except for a few functions. I'd appreciate any amount of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID's must be unique in a page so change to using classes. That is why you only get one set populated ... and with the last students data

You want to look inside each instance to populate instance specific elements which you do using `find()`.

By matching the data attribute names to attributes of the children we can also simplify writing them all out separately

```js
$('.student').each(function(){
   var $stu = $(this), // instance of student class
        data = $stu.data();// returns object with each data attribute as key
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
      // find within this student class instance
      $stu.find('.' + key).text(value)
   })
})
```

```css
.student{ border:2px solid #ccc; padding:10px; margin:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="student" data-studentname="Joan Andrews" data-studentdegree="Math II" data-studentgpa="999">
    <div class="studentname"></div>
    <div class="studentdegree"></div>
    <div class="studentgpa"></div>
</div>
<div  class="student" data-studentname="Alex Simmons" data-studentdegree="Science VI" data-studentgpa="0">
    <div class="studentname"></div>
    <div class="studentdegree"></div>
    <div class="studentgpa"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sometimes I'm more vulnerable to small oversights like these when I'm tired and in need of food. Thank you so much. This helped me a lot. I'm still learning bit by bit!

Comment: You were very much on the right track...I just advanced it a bit for you

Comment: Okay but now I need to fire off a `background-image` that uses a `data-attribute` from the `.student` `div`. It goes like this (I used the class values from your really really helpful answer):

`$(".studentname").css("background-image", "url('assets/images/students" + studentname + ".jpg')");`

How can I use the keys for this?

Comment: Use `$(this).find(".studentname")` on that line and change `+ studentname +` to `+ data.studentname +`. Note: not a good idea using spaces in filenames

Comment: I wish I could send you pizza. Thank you. I love you. You saved me from being insane tonight. Thank you so much for being helpful to the community!